# Custom Component - JInput Isn't Getting the Form Input

Tags: component, fix-my-code, jinput, file-upload

I have an input form in the admin view:

```
<form name="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file_upload" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_newsshowcase" />
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="upload" />
    <?php echo JHtml::_( 'form.token' ); ?>
</form>
```

This form calls the function upload() in the controller:

```
public function upload()
{
    // Check for request forgeries
    JSession::checkToken('request') or jexit(JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN'));
    $app = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $file = $app->files->get('file_upload');
    $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);
}
```

I've been echoing(debugging) the `$filename` and the `$file` variables, but no value is being echoed. When I echo something like:

```
echo '<pre>',print_r($file,1),'</pre>';
```

nothing is echoed. I assume that this means that the file to-be uploaded by this function is not being passed from the view to the controller?

**Update:** I also imported JInput explicitly (I saw mixed things on this in my searches saying that it isn't necessary, but wouldn't hurt). My original controller extended JController, I tried changing this to JControllerForm and changed the import dependency accordingly and still nothing.

**Update #2:** When I do a `var_dump` on `$_POST` I can see the form data, but when I do a `var_dump` on `$_FILES` it shows an empty array.

**Update #3:** The size of the image I am trying to upload, as a test, is 345 bytes(super small).

**Update #4:** I duplicated the form (removed the Joomla specific fields) in a separate stand-alone PHP file that linked to a PHP endpoint that did a `var_dump($_FILES)` and it displayed the upload data.

**Update #5:** Not sure if it matters, but the HTML form resides in the "default_body" section of the admin page.

Comment: What is the file path and classname of the controller?

Comment: Class name is: class NewsShowcaseController extends JController, "News Showcase" is the name of the custom component I'm building, path is: administrator/components/com_newsshowcase/controller.php

Comment: If you put a statement like `echo 'Anything';` in that upload function (toward the top), that is showing up, right?

Comment: Also just double checked all the code, and everything works for me. I'd check the file size of the file that you are uploading. It may exceed your php.ini limits.

Comment: When I put a 'echo "test";' after the $filename line it will show the word "test" printed out. I tried a smaller image and still no luck. I tried a couple of things that I added to the original post that, unfortunately, still didn't help.

Comment: Is the from saved using an AJAX request?

Comment: It is not using AJAX, it redirects to a blank admin page where my echoes are being printed. I should say that I commented out the upload code after what's listed in the controller so I can first make sure the file info is being handed to the controller accordingly.

Comment: I'd try a var_dump (or print_r) on the $_FILES super global. This sounds more like a server configuration than a coding issue to me.

Comment: I get an empty array when I do a var_dump($_FILES), what with the server configurations could it be?

Comment: Probably time to try things here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php

Comment: I actually came across that question/answer in a Google search and went down the list of the best answer with no new developments.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things.  First, verify this is a bug by using the deprecated but still working JRequest to get the file data.  I've had to resort to using this method myself recently for a file upload need.

```
$file = JRequest::getVar('file_upload', null, 'files', 'array');
```

If that doesn't work still, simply try dumping the $_FILES['file_upload'] request variable to confirm the file is being sent.  My thought is using JRequest will work.

Secondly, you should attach the upload method to the specific controller for the view.  Although you should and can reach a public method in your primary entry point, you should create and attach to a controller which will utilize the model/view.

In addition, once the task is migrated to the proper controller, no need to retrieve a JInput object as its already part of the parent class.

For arguments sake, lets say the view is Files, the controller look like so:

```
NewsShowcaseControllerFiles extends JControllerLegacy {

    public function upload() {
        jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
        jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
        // Check for request forgeries
        JSession::checkToken('request') or jexit(JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN'));

        // Notice in the controllers context, no need to instansiate Application Object
        $file = $this->input->files->get('file_upload');
        $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);

        // logic to save file or dump data to verify success
    }

}
```

In the primary controller entry point located in the components site/admin root add the following line to your display method to register your task:

```
$this->registerTask('files.upload', 'upload');
```

Last, you must alter the endpoint URL for the form or AJAX request handling the form submission:

```
JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_newsshowcase&task=files.upload');
```

Comment: While this is probably a better coding practice for Joomla, I'm not sure it helps at all with why he can't get the file information.

Comment: Excellent observation, edited answer to start with something specific for OP's issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am getting a NULL when I do a var_dump on the JRequest $file you suggested at the top of your answer

Comment: I'm also getting a NULL when I do a $_FILES['file_upload'] var_dump unfortunately

Comment: What about if you var_dump the $_FILES array?

Comment: Lol, then it sounds like a server or joomla configuration issue.  In back end of  joomla go to menu System > System Information and then select the PHP Information tab.  Check your PHP setting for maximum post, file count and size upload.

Comment: It says: file_uploads: on, max_file_uploads: 20, upload_max_filesize: 128m

Comment: When I do a print_r on $_POST though it shows the post data

Comment: Shot in the dark here, add a matching id attribute to the input with type file matching the name attribute of file_upload.  Then try using JInput to get file and dumping variable again.

Comment: Still no luck, unfortunately

Comment: Do I need to define/declare the file being uploaded in any component XML or elsewhere?

Comment: Back to your php.ini settings, what's the value for post_max_size?

Comment: I did a phpinfo() and it's set at 8M(see update)

Comment: Would anything need to change in the model for the upload functionality?

Comment: Try retrieving the files object using $app->get('FILES'); and see if the var_dump contains the request data.

Comment: A var_dump on $app->get('FILES'); outputs a NULL